# Echo it's terminal problem

Tags: command-line, echo

When I type

> echo `it's terminal`

or anything containing `'blah blah terminal blah blah` with echo the output shows

> Blockquote

what does this mean.

Comment: Please Google "bash quoting".

Comment: The ">" is a secondary prompt, and means that echo is waiting for you to enter the missing ending part of the command, here a quote, This is very basic programming syntax, Quotes comes in pairs, a start and an end. And if you need a single standing quote in between start and end, it must be escaped (marked) for the interpreter or compiler to understand it.

Comment: thankyou I completely missed ' in it's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal behaviour. `'` has a special meaning to bash: it quotes a string. The `>` prompt indicates that the command is not yet complete, and bash awaits further input. Indeed, you opened the quotes, that means bash expects a string that later is closed by another `'`.

You will have the result you expected with either one of

```
echo "it's terminal"
echo it\'s terminal
```

Comment: Thanks so ' in it's means I opend the quotes for the terminal and didn't closed it just learning a lot